# python SQL Variables in SELECT /WHERE

Tags: python, sql, pyqt, qsqlquery

I have a problem passing a variable like

```
query7 = QSqlQuery ("SELECT Exemplo FROM TabelaSubst WHERE Palavra="+text+" ORDER BY Exemple ASC;")
```

Im getting anything passing my variable text like this.
and if i do print query7.next() im getting false..

my program is with PYQT ,  i have a combobox, when i select some text from it, i pass this text to my variable "text", and i want to use it in my  *Where Palavra = text*, but i dont know how to do it. Im doing it because with it i will get examples of these texts and im putting it in a qtablewidget..

when i do a search with a word, like

```
query7 = QSqlQuery ("SELECT Exemplo FROM TabelaSubst WHERE Palavra='ronaldo' ORDER BY Exemple ASC;")
```

.. its ok.. i get my table with examples...
But if i change "ronaldo" for my variable text, i get anything..

The way im creating the table to put the examples is:

```
index1 = 0

while (query7.next()):
        self.tableWidget.setItem(index1,0,QTableWidgetItem(query7.value(0).toString()))  
        index1 = index1+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either wrap `text` in quotes, or put quotes into your query string.  For example:

```
text = "'%s'" % text
```

or

```
query7 = QSqlQuery ("SELECT Exemplo FROM TabelaSubst WHERE Palavra='"+text+"' ORDER BY Exemple ASC;")
```

Comment: Both of these methods leave your app open to SQL injection.

Comment: That's true, I just noticed that `text` comes from a combo box.  It should be cleaned up before being passed to the query.

Comment: i still getting false when i do  print query7.next()
with your 
query7 = QSqlQuery ("SELECT Exemplo FROM TabelaSubst WHERE Palavra='"+text+"' ORDER BY Exemple ASC;")

But if i change "+text+" for ronaldo and print query7.next() it returns true

Comment: and the "text" is from my db. I first open some text from my db into combobox then i want to make a search about this word, taking examples about it and using it in my qtablewidget

Comment: You can debug your program by printing values as they are created.  Put your query string into a temporary variable and print it out so you can see exactly what it looks like.  Then print out the value of `query7`, and so on.

Comment: Well, doing
query7 = QSqlQuery ("SELECT Exemplo FROM TabelaSubst WHEREPalavra='"+text+"';") return true and its ok.
I will search about this problem with ORDER BY. 
Thanks.